# How to change the playing speed of videos in HTML5 on mobile?

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

According to [this site](http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/2010/03/01/html-5-video-dom-attributes-and-events/), this is supported in the `playbackRate` and `defaultPlaybackRate` attributes, accessible via the DOM. But this is ***not working on mobile***. Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<video id="my-video" src="chubby-bubbies.ogv" ...></video>

<script type="text/javascript">
  /* play video twice as fast */
  document.getElementById("my-video").defaultPlaybackRate = 2.0;
  document.getElementById("my-video").play();

  /* now play three times as fast just for the heck of it */
  document.getElementById("my-video").playbackRate = 3.0;
</script>
```

The above works on Chrome, and also [Firefox 20 and above](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/20) on desktop.

Comment: I think it has to do with restrictions regarding html video on mobile. You can't control a video element until the user has hit play on said video. You can't force the video to start playing either through JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simply that Mobile Chrome (Android) doesn’t support playbackRate changes even tho this website says it does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#AutoCompatibilityTable

This is the **real** browser supported by playbackRate changes on mobile:

- Chrome 20+ ✔
- Firefox 20+ ✔
- IE 9+ ✔
- Safari 6+ ✔
- Opera 15+ ✔
- Mobile Chrome (Android) ✖
- Mobile Firefox 24+ ✔
- IE Mobile ✖
- Mobile Safari 6+ (iOS) ✔
- Opera Mobile ✖

I created a website and tested it by first adding the following to the web.config-file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
           <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Then I uploaded a simple video to my website and uploaded it to Azure for testing in the different browsers: http://pandasneezy.azurewebsites.net/

I suggest you use **Mobile Firefox 24+**, and it should work just fine with
: 
`document.getElementById("my-video").playbackRate = 3.0;`

Comment: In firefox HTML5 video playback rate works. Any idea how to adjust a youtube embedded video's playback rate. I tried with youtube's javascript API but it doesn't work on firefox and chrome.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22604934/html5-increase-youtube-speed-2x-from-url

Comment: I checked that. `player.setPlaybackRate(2);`  doesn't work on mobile chrome/firefox. It still plays at 1x speed

Comment: Mobile Firefox 24+ ✔ should be a ✖ then?

Comment: Yes, Mobile Firefox 24+ is  ✖ for mobile.